# Spark ML naive bayes class value to probability index mapping

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, naivebayes

Question May sound very obvious , but I have done lots of search to find the answer, yet not able to get full proof solution.

I am using Spark ML package and after running Naive Bayes getting proper results for probabilities, but not finding a way to map a particular class value with probability index (Not by looking at result I know which index is pointing to which class value from label column , but I want a programatic way, is there any way, in one of the document I found the class in label col which occurs most will have index 0 and so on, but what if multiple class will have same number of occurence)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
val firstResult = resultsDataFrame.select($"probability", $"prediction").first()
val probabilityVector = firstResult(0).asInstanceOf[Vector]
val prediction = firstResult(1).asInstanceOf[Double]
val probabilityIndex = if ((probabilityVector(0) < 0.5 && prediction == 0) || (probabilityVector(0) > 0.5 && prediction == 1)) 0 else 1
```

The probabilityIndex is what you are looking for